# How to avoid a tableCell scrolling when a tableCell have a view that accept user touch?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I add a UIView that can detect the user touch, drag in a table cell, but when I added it into a table cell. The tableview scrolling event get my touch instead, how can I avoid that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be i am wrong but this is trick works for me.

Use tableview **scrollEnabled** method for that.

In **cellForRowAtIndexPath** at where your Detect View is there set **scrollEnabled=NO** , and on view detect method set **scrollEnabled=YES**.

i.e if user has not selected tableview cell no. 5 table is not to scroll
so in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
..cell allocation...
  if (indexPath.row==4)
    {
        tableView.scrollEnabled=NO;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

not enable scrolling when user tap 5 no. cell.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.row==4)
    {
        tableView.scrollEnabled=YES;

    }
}
```